# GMail Calendar Invite from ics not rendering properly

Tags: gmail, icalendar

I have created an iCal file which has passed with 100% on http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net. I send the ical file with mimetype text/calendar to a gmail account, and I observe 3 different things to when I send a meeting request from yahoo calendar:

First, the "View on Google Calendar" link is broken, the URL is http://www.google.com/calendar/undefined.

Second, I don't get the Yes | No | Maybe buttons, but instead an "Add to Calendar" link

Yahoo Invite:
[image]

My App Invite:
[image]

Third, when I actually open the event in Google Calendar, I see a source field for yahoo events, but I don't get that on mine:

[image]

I have compared the ical files and can't see anything obvious that's different.

For reference, here is my ical file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//MyCompany//MyApp//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:this is the summary
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140504T120000
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140504T140000
DTSTAMP;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20140514T095627Z
UID:58cf4653e9da4fbaa27fbef1e9815d95@myapp.com
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:this is the description
ORGANIZER;CN="My App";ROLE=CHAIR:MAILTO:me@myapp.com
PRIORITY:5
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

So, my questions are:

1. How do I fix the "View on Google Calendar" link?
2. How do I get gmail to render the Yes Maybe No buttons?
3. How can I get the Source field to link back to my app?

I think the 3 are related - it seems Google is not fully recognising the calendar invite.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a starter, the METHOD property should be REQUEST and you should have some ATTENDEE properties (one with a value corresponding to the google email address) in your icalendar invitation for it to be recognized as such